# How can I set a task in Geany to be displayed in the "task tab" below?

Tags: ide, task, todo, geany

*I don't know if this question is ok for this forum, but since I think it is programming related I thought of it better handled here then in the superusers forum. If this is not the case, please move the question to the appropriate forum. Thanks you!*

I am using the [Geany IDE](http://www.geany.org/) for coding. To be more productive I installed the [Geany plugin package](http://plugins.geany.org/addons.html). But somehow I can't figure out how to get my tasks displayed in the **task tab**.

The description for the tasks plugin is, I quote:

Tasks

> The tasks plugin goes through a file being edited and picks out lines
>   with configurable keywords (e.g. "TODO" or "FIXME") in them. It
>   collects the text after those words and puts them in a new "Tasks" tab
>   in the message window. Clicking on a task in that tab takes you to the
>   line in the file where the task was defined.

In my **python script** I marked my tasks as

```
# @TODO My Task
# TODO: My Task
# @TODO: My Task
# TODO My Task
```

But they **don't get displayed in the task tab**. By the way, I activated the tasks plugin in geany's plugin manager already.

What do I miss?

Comment: Silly me: All of the examples above were displayed in the *tasks tab* after a **restart** of geany! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me: All of the examples above were displayed in the tasks tab after a restart of geany! ^^